# I have an error sending email to reset a password in ruby on rails with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When the users in my application try to recover their password by an email they get the next error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED in Devise::PasswordsController#create

Connection refused - connect(2)
```

I cant understant why this is happening. Please help.

Comment: this appears to possibly be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395128/getting-devise-authentication-to-send-the-email-for-password-retrieval  you should go there, and open a bounty

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have set smtp properly,

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  authentication: 'plain',
  user_name: 'myemail@gmail.com',
  password: '<password>'
}
```